# Move attributes to description tab

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd

I  am using the rwd theme of magento 1.9.0.1,and i want to move the attributes in additional information tab to description tab,how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Hello `additional information tab` will only those `Attributes` which attributes are mark on display on product view page as below Image.

[image]

If you want to display Some attributes on `description tab` then you can find the tab in `view.phtml`.

use the code to display values of custom attributes.

> echo $product->getData('ATTRIBUTE CODE');

OR  suppose you are facing `color` attribute.

> echo $product->getColor();

This way you can fetch the `Attributes` value on front-end side.

let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Thank you for you help.I want to move the attributes table from additional information tab  to product description tab,how?

Comment: you have to check the catalog.xml file

Comment: I have tried,but not success.